# How do you prevent Microsoft Word date insert from updating on default?

Tags: microsoft-word

I know you can unlink a date insert from updating with ctrl + shift + f9, but that is too much work for what should be default behavior. Is there a way to generate date inserts that do not update by default, saving me unnecessary keyboard gymnastics?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to prevent update of fields, why don't you just insert them as text?

To quickly insert current date you can

- go to Insert - Date (Alt + N - D)
- here you can select your desired format (can even save it as default format)
- then press OK (enter)

[image]

Comment: It's still more actions than using only one shortcut. Isn't there a way to generate the current, unpdating date with one hotkey?

Comment: in your question you want it not to update, and now you ask about inserting an updating field, what do you need?? After setting default format it just Alt+N,D and Enter. Yes it's indeed longer then a combination of two keys, but I don't really see a practical use where the time to press that extra two buttons matters.